# How to raise property change events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, propertychanged

I have the following javascript data model:

```
function User(uid, usr_name, usr_pwd, usr_enbld) {
    var id = uid == null ? uuid.v4() : uid;
    var name = usr_name;
    var password = usr_pwd;
    var enabled = usr_enbld;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "id", {
        get: function () {
            return id;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
        get: function () {
            return name;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            name = value;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, "password", {
        get: function () {
            return password;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            password = value;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, "enabled", {
        get: function () {
            return enabled;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            if (!value instanceof Boolean) {
                // log - type error, must be true/false
                return;
            }
            enabled = value;
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to find out how to raise events when one of the properties are changed. The observer libraries I've found for nodejs all seem very difficult. Maybe I didn't implement it properly, but I thought that I would be able to use bind`and`trigger` on a "propertyChanged" event. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's yet in ECMAScript but later they are going to provide something like [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe), which will bind the objects to a function.

If you are using `chrome 36` or above you should be able to use this in console.

```
// Let's say we have a model with data
var model = {};

// Which we then observe
Object.observe(model, function(changes){

    // This asynchronous callback runs
    changes.forEach(function(change) {

        // Letting us know what changed
        console.log('Printing Changes.');
        console.log(change.type, change.name, change.oldValue);
    });

});
```

Now if you will add, remove, or modify a property of model it'll call the function.

You might want to look at [**watch**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch), but if you'll look at MDN, they say it's not recommended to use this.

**Note:-** If you want to use `Observe` with `node` its not available in current stable version of nodejs, but you can go for **node v0.11.*** which supports this feature.

If you are using `node v0.11` make sure to run your program as

```
node --harmony filename.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing a little bit of the C# paradigm, I figured out a solution. Using a different model, though `UserDetail` I've prototyped the following:

```
user_detail.__proto__.propertyChange = null;
user_detail.__proto__.notify = function(args){
    if(user_detail.propertyChange !== null){
        user_detail.propertyChange(args);
    }
};
```

...then in the model's property setter:

```
set: function (value) {
    if(forename !== value){
        var args = {
            property: "forename",
            old: forename,
            new: value
        };
        forename = value;
        this.notify(args);
    }
}
```

Unit test and following output:

```
var propChanged = false;
usrDetails.propertyChange = function(data){
    console.log("model [" + usrDetails.constructor.name + "] property changed:");
    console.log("  property  :" + data.property);
    console.log("  old value :" + data.old);
    console.log("  new value :" + data.new);

    propChanged = true;
};
usrDetails.forename = "Ethan";
```

> --- test property change event ---
>   model [UserDetail] property changed:
>      property  :forename
>      old value :David
>      new value
>   :Ethan model [UserDetail] retrieved: Ethan Boarman